# SER 4 wires from meter to main panel

Tags: electrical

I’m installing a 200amp service to my shop. Here’s the layout: meter socket (no disconnect) back to back with 200 amp main breaker panel. I went to a local electrical supply house told them what I was doing and they gave me SER 4/0-4/0-/40-2/0. My understanding was the I only need 3 wires from the meter to the first disconnect. So what should I do with the 4th wire? My meter socket does have a separate ground lug as does my load center, can I just connect them there? Seems this would be accomplishing the same purpose as bonding neutral and ground. The other option would be to strip the sheath from the SER and just run the 3 4/0 XHHW conductors. Advice?

Comment: Or just don’t connect that wire?

Comment: Why no disconnect? A disconnect at the meter is the DIYers very best friend, and they're cheap now. You'll wish you had it later, we deal with lots of people who wish they had it!

Comment: Also is a second 200A service at the shop really necessary? You may regret it later, the power companies seem to be shifting to a "charge you for the right to have the service" model.  Our town (muni power) charges $60/month for each of our 2 services even if we cancel the service - really - for "the right to have service there".  I asked if we knocked the buildings down and grew corn, would we still owe? They said yes.  This is how they're financing grid maintenance now.

Comment: Meter sockets are extremely hard to find right now it’s all I could get my hands on. It’s a big (4200 sq ft) shop/warehouse built on the site of a former home. Pole and transformer 30’ away.

Comment: Going to a panel will require 4 wires in almost every case unless a metal grounding conduit was used. Code requires disconnects at the service today unless in conduit to the main for the states that do not have a main disconnect. Years ago I could do everything as I could pull the meter, today I suggest a 30-40 meter or 320 in some places as a feeder if you are upgrading as a on demand water heater a large car charger on a minimum service is close 250 amps if you have gas and the full 320 for electric and I don’t live in a super cold or hot area.

Comment: Were you planning on running a conduit from the meter to the panel to begin with?

Comment: Yes there will be a short conduit through the wall from meter box to panel.

Comment: Just make sure you're not on NEC 2020 or the meter-main will be mandatory whether it's easy to find or not.  (in fact one would explain the other lol).

Comment: I talked to the inspector today. He instructed me to run the solid copper ground from the ground lug in the meter box to the rods. No ground conductor between meter and panel since the ground and neutral are bonded in both the meter base and the main panel.